# not understanding jquery $(this) correctly

Tags: jquery

I think that I am misunderstanding something about how jquery `$(this)` works. In my code below:

```
$(document).delegate(".ISBN_number", "change", 
        function()
        {
            var isbnNum = $(this).val();
            console.log("isbnNum = " + isbnNum);
            $.get("validate_isbn.php", {isbn: isbnNum},
                function(answer) 
                {                   
                    console.log("answer = " + answer);    //this does display the correct content
                    if (answer == true)
                    {   console.log("entered answer");
                        $(this).after("<img src='pics/green_checkmark.png' class='checkmark'>");
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        $(this).after("nope");
                    }
            });             
    });
```

I am trying to select any input tag when its contents are changed. When I call `$(this`) in the code, I assumed that it would refer back to this input tag but it doesn't. What is my issue? Is it because I used `.delegate`? (I needed to use this because the input tags are generated dynamically later on, they don't exist in the original code.) How can I fix this?

Comment: which `$(this)` are you referring to? there are like three of them, and two of them are probably in a wildly different context than you expect.

Comment: I'm refering to the second (and third, though, I was only using that as a test) $(this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access `this` from the `.delegate()` call, then you have to save it into a local variable because `this` is set to something different in the completion function for the ajax call.  You can do that like this:

```
$(document).delegate(".ISBN_number", "change", 
        function()
        {
            var self = this;
            var isbnNum = $(this).val();
            console.log("isbnNum = " + isbnNum);
            $.get("validate_isbn.php", {isbn: isbnNum},
                function(answer) 
                {                   
                    console.log("answer = " + answer);    //this does display the correct content
                    if (answer == true)
                    {   console.log("entered answer");
                        $(self).after("<img src='pics/green_checkmark.png' class='checkmark'>");
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        $(self).after("nope");
                    }
            });             
    });
```

Comment: This is not really standard practice. Jasper has it right with caching `$(this)` specifically and prepending `$` to know you're referring to a jQuery object.

Comment: @JoshSmith - `var self = this;` is very much a standard javascript practice, used by many people.  Of course, if you only need `$(this)`, then it's fine to cache that instead.  Using $ in the var name of jQuery objects is a personal style which I know some people like, but I dislike as I find it lessens readability.

Comment: @JoshSmith - I find that too many jQuery folks are obsessed with always using jQuery methods and will write code like this: `$(this).attr("id")` instead of `this.id` or `$(this).val()` instead of `this.value` when the jQuery way is multiple function calls instead of a single property reference.  As such, I usually cache `this` rather than `$(this)` since it's the more fundamental value.  But, full optimization for a particular situation depends upon the needs of the situation and caching `$(this)` works fine in this circumstance.

Comment: Fair enough. I'd +1 your last comment but my vote limit's reached. Know that it's in my heart. :)

Answer (score 4):

`this` (`var isbnNum = $(this).val();`) refers to the `.ISBN_number` element that had the `change` event fire on it. `$(this)` refers to that same DOM element wrapped in a jQuery object so you can call jQuery functions on it.

When you make an AJAX call or any other type of function call that uses an anonymous function it is good practice to cache the original `this`:

```
$(document).delegate(".ISBN_number", "change", 
        function()
        {
            var $this   = $(this),
                isbnNum = $this.val();
            console.log("isbnNum = " + isbnNum);
            $.get("validate_isbn.php", {isbn: isbnNum},
                function(answer) 
                {                   
                    console.log("answer = " + answer);    //this does display the correct content
                    if (answer == true)
                    {   console.log("entered answer");
                        $this.after("<img src='pics/green_checkmark.png' class='checkmark'>");
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        $this.after("nope");
                    }
            });             
    });
```

That way you know you're always referring to the same `this`.

Comment: Wow, edited at approximately the same time to add in caching. Good deal.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` refers to the current scope. In your case the first `$(this)` refers to the `.ISBN_number`, and the other `$(this)` are in a different scope.

You should be caching the first `$(this)` like so:

```
$(document).delegate(".ISBN_number", "change", 
    function()
    {
        $isbn = $(this);
        var isbnNum = $isbn.val();
        console.log("isbnNum = " + isbnNum);
        $.get("validate_isbn.php", {isbn: isbnNum},
            function(answer) 
            {                   
                console.log("answer = " + answer);    //this does display the correct content
                if (answer == true)
                {   console.log("entered answer");
                    $isbn.after("<img src='pics/green_checkmark.png' class='checkmark'>");
                }
                else 
                {
                    $isbn.after("nope");
                }
        });             
});
```

Comment: but why doesn't my code work? Is it because of the .after? I have used this same code elsewhere (where it is also adding info after the input element) and there it worked!

Comment: In addition to what Josh said, I woiuld point you [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/fully-understanding-the-this-keyword/) to fully understand `this` keyword

Answer (score 0):

`this` may change for code inside a callback function. However, you should be able to circumvent that by using a caching variable:

```
$(document).delegate(".ISBN_number", "change", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var isbnNum = $this.val();
    console.log("isbnNum = " + isbnNum);
    $.get("validate_isbn.php", {
        isbn: isbnNum
    }, function (answer) {
        console.log("answer = " + answer); //this does display the correct content 
        if (answer == true) {
            console.log("entered answer");
            $this.after("<img src='pics/green_checkmark.png' class='checkmark'>");
        } else {
            $this.after("nope");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: or use the jquery Event object. http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: @32bitkid How would that be better, though? Using the event object leads to both longer code and more processing.

Comment: more processing? longer code? what? the event object is being passed to your closure whether you bind a variable to it or not...

Comment: @32bitkid Please submit an answer with your intention, then. You and I must be thinking about different things.

Answer (score 0):

If you have inputBox for ISBN number, #(this).val() gives you the value entered/changed in the text Box.